How to resize buttons in angular material m3?
I have some buttons which should be larger then the normal size. I found some code for previous versions:
$my-custom-input: mat.define-typography-level(
    $font-family: 'Roboto',
    $font-weight: 400,
    $font-size: 1rem,
    $line-height: 1,
    $letter-spacing: 'normal'
  );

  /* Merge custom configs into existing config */
  $my-typography-config: map.merge(
    mat.define-typography-config(
      /* 'button'-property will work out of the box */
      $button: $my-custom-button
    ),
  );

but define-typography-level is not defined anymore. How can I do this in the newest version without just overriding css?

A solution without resorting to mat-typography is to add this in your styles.scss:
.big {
  --mdc-text-button-label-text-size: 1.5rem;
}

A button with larger text would then be styled as follows:
<button class="big" mat-button>The Big Button</button>

Good luck with your project.

You can first include typography-hierarchy  into your theme.
Angular Material - Tutorial
@include mat.typography-hierarchy($theme); //  Added

Then you have a wide range of classes to configure the typography.
Material typography docs
| CSS class                 | Typesale level      |
|---------------------------|---------------------|
| `.mat-display-large`      | `display-large`     |
| `.mat-display-medium`     | `display-medium`    |
| `.mat-display-small`      | `display-small`     |
| `.mat-headline-large`     | `headline-large`    |
| `.mat-headline-medium`    | `headline-medium`   |
| `.mat-headline-small`     | `headline-small`    |
| `.mat-title-large`        | `title-large`       |
| `.mat-title-medium`       | `title-medium`      |
| `.mat-title-small`        | `title-small`       |
| `.mat-body-large`         | `body-large`        |
| `.mat-body-medium`        | `body-medium`       |
| `.mat-body-small`         | `body-small`        |
| `.mat-label-large`        | `label-large`       |
| `.mat-label-medium`       | `label-medium`      |
| `.mat-label-small`        | `label-small`       |

Just add the class mat-title-medium to the button and you will be able to set the typography of the button.
<section>
  <div class="example-label">Basic</div>
  <div class="example-button-row">
    <button mat-button class="mat-body-large">Basic</button>
    <button mat-button disabled class="mat-body-large">Disabled</button>
    <a mat-button href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" class="mat-body-large">Link</a>
  </div>
</section>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<section>
  <div class="example-label">Raised</div>
  <div class="example-button-row">
    <button mat-raised-button class="mat-body-large">Basic</button>
    <button mat-raised-button disabled class="mat-body-large">Disabled</button>
    <a mat-raised-button href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" class="mat-body-large">Link</a>
  </div>
</section>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<section>
  <div class="example-label">Stroked</div>
  <div class="example-button-row">
    <button mat-stroked-button class="mat-body-large">Basic</button>
    <button mat-stroked-button disabled class="mat-body-large">Disabled</button>
    <a mat-stroked-button href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" class="mat-body-large"
      >Link</a
    >
  </div>
</section>

Stackblitz Demo
